# Will this algorithm terminate?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, infinite-loop, halting-problem

With different values in a collection, will this algorithm (pseudeocode) ever terminate?

```
while (curElement != average(allElements))
{
    curElement = average(allElements);
    nextElement();
}
```

Note that I'm assuming that we will re-start from the beginning if we're at the end of the array.

Comment: What does nextElement() do and is the allElements() collection constant?

Comment: how you are calculating `average(allElements)`

Comment: It depends on your values in that collection. average(allElements) will return fractional values or absolute?

Comment: @RoyDictus: It's supposed to be pseudocode. Just imagine that nextElement() moves the pointer curElement to the next element of the collection, or to the beginning if we're at the end.

Comment: @RoyDictus: Oh, and allElements will be changed when curElement is set.

Comment: Your last sentence does already give you the answer: It might not terminate depending on the actual values (at least for *n* > 1 elements).

Comment: @Gumbo: Why? The loop will terminate if the current element equals the average of the collection.

Comment: @Franz And what if there is no such element? Just think of `(1, 3)` where the average is 2.

Comment: It obviously does not terminate in the case that all elements are equal.

Comment: I think you want `curElement = nextElement()` [typo?] in the loops, otherwise - the answer is trivial: if you enter the loop once -you exit immidiately, since currElement is defined to be the average

Comment: @amit: no, nextElement() advances curElement to point at the next element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is pseudocode, a simple example with 2 elements will reveal that there are cases where the program won't terminate:

```
x = 0, y = 1;

          x     y
Step 1:   0.5   1
Step 2:   0.5   0.75
Step 3:   0.635 0.75
//and so one
```

With some math involved, `lim(x-y) = lim( 1 / 2^n )`

So the numbers converge, but they're never equal.

However, if you'd actually implement this on a computer, they will turn out equal because of hardware limitations - not all numbers can be expressed in a limited number of bits.

Comment: There exist arbitrary precision real-number implementations, which would allow for a real-life implementation to run forever.

Comment: @bdares I doubt that. They still store the number in memory, and as large as it gets, it's not infinite.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: You can store the number in disk/remote cluster and expand it on the fly. Theoretically, it can be done.

Comment: Hmmm... good point.  @amit any real-life storage is finite, so his argument still holds.

Comment: @bdares: (1) You can expand the cluster on the fly, so it is infinite. (2) You could say that the universe will collapse at some point in time, and there are finite number of atoms in the universe, so every implementation of any algorithm is `O(1)` space & time. But I don't think that's what the discussion is about.

Comment: :))) phylosophy.stackexchange.com. Okay then, I think we can all agree that theoretically it will never end, but in practice it will, right?

Comment: I guess it comes down to whether or not we're considering theoretical programs running on theoretical machines (such as the Turing machine, with infinite memory), or a real-life machine with real constraints.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

If your elements hold discrete values, then most likely they will fall into the same value after a few runs.

If your elements hold limited precision values (such as floats or doubles), then it will take longer, but finite time.

If your elements hold arbitrary precision values, then your algorithm may never finish.  (If you count up every piece of an integral and add it to a figure you have on a piece of paper, you need infinite time, an infinitely large piece of paper, and infinite patience with this analogy.)

There is little difference between your code and the following:

```
var i = 1;
while (i != 0) 
    i = i / 2;
```

Will it ever terminate?  That really depends on the implementation.